# Weird NSString vs NSURL behavior

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have a class which parse an XML feed. In that class I have to following method:

```
-(id)loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString name:(NSString*)name{
  NSString *urls = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@%@" , urlString, name];
  NSLog(@"STRING URL: %@" , urls);
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urls];

  NSLog(@"%@" , url);

  parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
  parser.delegate = self;
  BOOL success = [parser parse];
  if (success) {
      NSLog(@"No error");
  }else{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@" , parser.parserError);
}
    return self;
}
```

The first NSLog is the correct url, however the NSURL comes out as (null)

Here's where I call the method:

```
 //f is an object where I store the value of name from another feed, which I have to use as a parameter in the url for this feed

 NSString *name = f.name; 
        myParser = [[MyParser alloc]loadXMLByURL:@"http://myurl.com/names.asp?name=" name:name];
```

If I NSLog name here, it shows the right value.

Anyone have any idea why the NSURL comes out as (null)?

Comment: It's just a string containing the parameters I need to parse the other XML feed. And like I wrote above, the correct values comes out when I NSLog it.

Comment: Can you post the output of the first `NSLog`? You are not escaping the name string, thus there could be characters in there that are not valid for a URL...

Comment: I tried to escape the name string, with NSUTF8 and NSASCII, the url is not (null) anymore. Looks like this: http://myurl.com/names.asp?name=%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20ARN. When the url is like that, it doesn't have any nodes in the xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to escape `name`.

Add a category on `NSString` and then call `[name urlEncodedString]`. e.g.:

```
@implementation NSString (URLEncoding)

- (NSString *)urlEncodedString
{
    return (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                               (CFStringRef)self,
                                                               NULL,
                                                               (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",
                                                               kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
}

@end
```

Comment: NSString *encodedString = [name urlEncodedString]; gives a warning saying: NSString may not respond to -urlEncodedString. App crashes on launch

Comment: Did you add a category on `NSString`? Did you import the category?

Comment: I tried NSString *encodedString = [name stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; then the string is fine, but the URL is (null) again. WTF

Comment: `encodedString = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                               (CFStringRef)name,
                                                               NULL,
                                                               (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",
                                                               kCFStringEncodingUTF8);`

Comment: I did that, url now is: http://myurl.com/names.asp?name=%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520ARN

Comment: It's three characters. Ex: BGO. http://myurl.com/names.asp?name=BGO This gives me one node in the xml feed with the value I need

Comment: You have a new line and spaces before it. `NSString *timmedString = [name stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                                  [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];` and then `encodedString = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)timmedString, NULL, (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following..

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat::@"%@%@" , urlString, name]]];
parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: data];
parser.delegate = self;
BOOL success = [parser parse];
if (success) {
    NSLog(@"No error");
}else{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@" , parser.parserError);
}
return self;
```

Comment: I tried this, and put an NSLog on data, comes out (null) too.

Comment: your urlString must be `http://myurl.com/names.asp?name=` and name should be any name that you want.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for, yes.